# Unexpected token "." when using .bind() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bind

Was just trying out a proof of concept with `.bind()` and noticed that if I try to use `.bind()` in this code, I get an unexpected token ".":

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function(){
        function bar(){
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(this); // errors
        bar();
    }
}

myObj.foo();
```

However, if I do this:

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function(){
        var bar = function(){
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(this);
        bar();
    }
}

myObj.foo();
```

It's fine. No errors. Can someone explain this behaviour please? I'm guessing it's to do with when the function is parsed, but if someone has a more in-depth explanation, that'd be great!

Comment: The first version is a function declaration, while the second is an assignment of a function _value_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind()` is a method on `Function.prototype`. Thus it's supposed to be called on the function object and will return a new function with the same body but different value bound to `this`.

When using function declaration (your first scenario), you'll not getting a function object in return (your first scenario), thus error. There is nothing to call `bind()` on.

Second one works, because your assigning a function to the variable, so you get a function object.

Consider:

```
function a() {
   return this.variable;
}

a(); // === undefined, because "this" is bound to the global object, 
     // and global object does not have "variable" defined.
     // When not in strict mode, global object === window (in browser env).

var b = window.a.bind({variable: 'value'});
    // Since a() was declared, it is a property of the global object (window).
    // Lets get it and bind to some object.

b(); // === 'value' - because 'b' is essentialy 'a' bound to {variable: 'value'}.

window.variable = 'other value';  // assign variable to global object
a(); // === 'other value'
b(); // === 'value' - it is not bound to global object, so no change here.
```

So in your example you could do:

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function(){
        function bar(){
            console.log('this', this);
        }

        var bar2 = bar.bind(this);
        bar2();

        // Or:
        // bar.bind(this)();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also good to note that it's not a function expression as declarations have "higher priority" - to make it one, you should either assign it to a variable or use parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got more why it was working than why it wasn't. I think I need to understand more what's happening in a function declaration under the hood.

Comment: @benhowdle89 - sure, glad I helped. If you want to get to understand functions, bind, scopes etc. in more detail, there is nothing I could recommend more than [Dmitry Soshinkov's blog series](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/) - read it twice or so and you'll get it all :)